# What protocol is used to reliably transmit a word document from your computer to someone else?

Tags: tcpip

Answer is TCP but i thought it should be SMTP.
I am confuse

Comment: I too, am confuse

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149

Comment: _"TCP provides **reliable, ordered, and error-checked** delivery of a stream of octets (bytes) between applications running on hosts communicating by an IP network._ - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: Your question and answer do not make sense. SMTP runs over TCP, but none directly deals with "word document". Have a look at the Internet network stack to separate the various parts, based on their goal.

Comment: This sounds like a dumb exam. you have to know the mind of your teacher and his stupid material that he wants you to memorise. But you should know SMTP is email

Comment: There is nothing special about a word document compared with any file which needs to be reliably transmitted.

Comment: Can you expand the question to better describe the test question you were responding to (was it a fill-in-the-blank, multiple choice and what choices, etc.)?  Without more context, the question is pretty broad, looking like a bad test question where we have no idea what specific knowledge or thought process the instructor was trying to measure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer to this question - it is, in effect, nonsensical and there are a huge number of ways this could be done.

There are also different types of protocols.

The lower level protocols include TCP, UDP and a few other less commonly used ones, including protocols used for traffic management and some VPNs.   **The most commonly used low level protocol would typically be TCP** - as it has built in functionality to resend missing or corrupt packets, however solutions which run over UDP and do their own checks are becoming practical (Google QUIC protocol uses UDP).  Other protocols could conceivably be used as well.

Above this you then have the application protocols - and these will typically sit on top of UDP or TCP - and this is where the choices become hugely overwhelming.   They include using SMB (local file sharing), FTP (old way to upload files to systems, very complex protocol) ad HTTP .   All of these are insecure.   Then you get secure protocols like HTTPS and SCP - all of these are common for transferring files reliably.

Sending files by encoding them and sending them through a mail / store-and-foward system expands the number of possibilities hugely - this includes encoding files in a way that mail systems will cope with and sending them - usually via SMTP.

There are a plethora of other, less common ways of transmitting the file across a network - and indeed some of these don't even require Internet.  I've not commented on these.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the question - and its a very bad question - but possibly not quite as bad as it appears on it's multiple choice - the answer of TCP instead of SMTP would be because the question is trying to tease out the requirement for sending reliably - which historically implied TCP.

The answer SMTP is presumably considered wrong because the expectation is to know there are many higher level protocols, not only TCP, and SMTP transmissions are not guaranteed - especially because of things like spam filters and mail limits.

The answer TCP is, however wrong for a multitude of reasons, because TCP is not unique in its ability to reliably transmit a file - zmodem, an ancient protocol which does not use the Internet would be a more valid answer as it bot handles reliability and transmit the file!

Comment: If you are going to write multiple answers please make sure they are complete. Your 2nd paragraph is lacking some text after **especially becau** :)

Answer (score -1):

SMTP stands for Simple Mail Transfer protocol. It is used to send e-mails to another person. Ms word documenta can be sent through any protocol like HTTP and FTP.